# Enable background to edit and work when open bootstrap modal popup

Tags: angularjs

I have kendo grid which has inline edit and i have modal popup to show the updates on particular event which keep refreshes and populates the data.

When the modal i sopened i couldnt do edit in kendo grid.

I am using Angular 1.4.7.

Answer (score 0):

Since it is the behaviour of the modal poup we cant edit or make focus. From the angular libaray it is forced to be focused on Modal popup. I modified in Angular library to stop forcing the focus into Modal popup when the grey hide is hidden.

Thats how i achieved on what i wanted.